# Java packaging and uploading to a PPA in Launchpad

Tags: package-management, java, application-development, deb, packaging

I have a java application (created as a class) and I want to know how I can (or should I even) convert it to .deb format and then how to upload it to a Launchpad PPA so that everyone could install it?

Notice that I am still learning Java, so my program does not have any GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Packaging is quite a long process and here I am assuming that you are ready to go through the trouble. Since Ubuntu is based on Debian and fetches almost all the packages from the Debian repository, I believe the packaging schemes in both are the same. Please refer to this : http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/

Comment: We had a session on it last sunday. Do read it about it if you're interested. http://sosaysharis.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/debianutsavam-2012-medal-of-honor/

Comment: sure I am, I am planning (in future) to create apps for Ubuntu so I am interested in any material related to programming :)